# Oracle sql update only if id exist else return an error message

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In mongoDB i remember there is a findOneAndUpdate query. Do we have or atleast can we create a query in oracle sql that only updates record if it exists otherwise will return a no data found message? I tried this query below however it updates all the record when a result is found:

```
UPDATE 
    user
SET 
    fname=:lname,
    lname=:fname
WHERE
    EXISTS (
         SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=:id
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be just

```
update t_user set
  fname = :lname,
  lname = :fname
where id = :id;
```

It won't return an error if nothing's being updated, though, so - if it is actually a PL/SQL procedure, you'll have to check it yourself, e.g. (right behind the above `UPDATE` statement):

```
if sql%rowcount = 0 then
   dbms_output.put_line('No rows have been updated');
end if;
```